# Can I assign a nested function to a parameter of the parent function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

My question is basic and simple (I think). It is possibly a duplicate and I couldn't use the right keywords to search and find it.

Why does the following code work:

```
let rAMessage = 'Ride along, everyone!'

let messageNum = 5

function computeNumber() {
      return 5+5
    }

function RideAlong(message, number = computeNumber()) {
    alert(`${message} + ${number}`)
}

RideAlong(rAMessage)
```

But this code doesn't:

```
let rAMessage = 'Ride along, everyone!'

let messageNum = 5

function RideAlong(message, number = computeNumber()) {
    function computeNumber() {
      return 5+5
    }
    alert(`${message} + ${number}`)
}

RideAlong(rAMessage)
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It's not scoped properly - at the point that arguments (and default parameters) are evaluated, the function proper has not started yet, so `computeNumber` can't be seen from the parameter list. I'd put `computeNumber` outside of `RideAlong` instead (or encapsulated in an IIFE, if you want to prevent it from being visible to code outside, like where `RideAlong` is being called)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think I got it. The reason I tried this and wanted to know why it doesn't work is the following segment from javascript.info:

function showMessage(from, text = anotherFunction()) {
  // anotherFunction() only executed if no text given
  // its result becomes the value of text
}

I must've misinterpreted something. Any idea what is it?

Edit: It's the last example in the 'Default Values' section. Here: http://javascript.info/function-basics#default-values

Comment: @CertainPerformance Got it. Thank you. I should've just re-read that segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear how you want that second function to work. But it looks like you want the option to pass in a `number` argument and have the default be the result of `computeNumber` without having defined outside the function. It's probably easiest to calculate the defualt inside the function:

```js
let rAMessage = 'Ride along, everyone!'

function RideAlong(message, number) {
    function computeNumber() {
      return 5+5
    }
    if (number === undefined) number = computeNumber()
    console.log(`${message} + ${number}`)
}

RideAlong(rAMessage)

RideAlong(rAMessage, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. I misinterpreted the following statement from javascript.info:

function showMessage(from, text = anotherFunction()) {
  // anotherFunction() only executed if no text given
  // its result becomes the value of text
}

Can you help me with an example to demonstrate what the author is trying to say?

Comment: @MuhabSelim, in your second example, if you pass the second argument to the function `RideAlong(rAMessage, 5)` you won't get the error because it doesn't try to execute the `computeNumber` function. That function is only executed as a default if no argument exists. I think that's what the author is talking about.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.